# The bootbox dialog window can't scroll vertically?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootbox

in the code user is able to click on the button and bootbox window will display data. There is edit button, and if user clicks on that button current window should close and new modal dialog window displays form. When new modal window is displayed it can't be scrolled vertically. Here is example of my code:

```js
var data = {
  1: {
    "recid": 1,
    "name": "John Holmes",
    "age": 48,
    "title": "Manager"
  },
  2: {
    "recid": 2,
    "name": "Jackie Troy",
    "age": 45,
    "title": "Engineer"
  },
  3: {
    "recid": 3,
    "name": "Mike Cook",
    "age": 28,
    "title": "Secretary"
  },
  4: {
    "recid": 4,
    "name": "Roy Thomson",
    "age": 56,
    "title": "HR Coordinator"
  },
  5: {
    "recid": 5,
    "name": "Ana Olsen",
    "age": 23,
    "title": "Lead Developer"
  }
};

function dialogBox(title, message, size) {
  title = title || 'HCS System';
  message = message || 'HCS Dialog Box';
  size = size || 'lg';

  var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: true,
    size: size,
    title: '<strong>' + title + '</strong>',
    message: message
  });
  dialog.prop("id", "dialog-box");
};

$("#show-data").on("click", function() {
  var dialogTitle = "Data History",
    table = $('<table>').addClass('table'),
    thead = $('<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Title</th></tr></thead>'),
    tbody = $('<tbody>');

  if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    var tr = $('<tr><td colspan="3">No records were found.</td></tr>');
    tbody.append(tr);
  } else {
    for (key in data) {
      var tr = $('<tr>').prop('id', 'row_' + key);
      tbody.append(tr);
      tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].name ? data[key].name : "N/A"));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].age ? data[key].age : "N/A"));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].title ? data[key].title : "N/A"));
      tr.append($('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary edit-data" data-recid="' + key + '">Edit</button></td>'));
    }
  }

  table.append(thead);
  table.append(tbody);
  dialogBox(dialogTitle, table, "xl");
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit-data", function() {
  $("#dialog-box").modal("hide");
  var recID = $(this).data("recid");

  if (!$.isEmptyObject(data[recID])) {
    $("#frm_name").val(data[recID].name);
    $("#frm_age").val(data[recID].age);
    $("#frm_title").val(data[recID].title);
    $("#frm_modal").modal("show");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.3.2/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" type="button" id="show-data">Show Data</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="frm_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="frm-data" name="data_frm" id="data_frm" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="frm_name">Name:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_name" id="frm_name" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="50" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="frm_age">Age:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_age" id="frm_age" placeholder="Enter Age" maxlength="2" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="frm_title">Title:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_title" id="frm_title" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="100" required>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary review-apply" data-modal="er_modal" data-update-option="">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run this example click on Show Data and you will see first window. Then if you click on Edit modal form will display on the screen. If you try to scroll only background will move vertically but modal window doesn't move. If anyone knows how to fix that please let me know.

Comment: when i try to scroll nothing happens for me which browser u r using ?

Comment: I tried Chrome and Firefox. Even here if you run example modal with the form data doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you hide your first modal with the metod `$("#dialog-box").modal("hide");` you also remove `.modal-open` to your `body` tag

That class add a `overflow-y: auto;` to `.modal-open .modal` element.

A solution could be to force the addition of that class when the hide event is over using a [Modal's event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events):

```
$("#dialog-box").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
})
```

```js
var data = {
  1: {
    "recid": 1,
    "name": "John Holmes",
    "age": 48,
    "title": "Manager"
  },
  2: {
    "recid": 2,
    "name": "Jackie Troy",
    "age": 45,
    "title": "Engineer"
  },
  3: {
    "recid": 3,
    "name": "Mike Cook",
    "age": 28,
    "title": "Secretary"
  },
  4: {
    "recid": 4,
    "name": "Roy Thomson",
    "age": 56,
    "title": "HR Coordinator"
  },
  5: {
    "recid": 5,
    "name": "Ana Olsen",
    "age": 23,
    "title": "Lead Developer"
  }
};

function dialogBox(title, message, size) {
  title = title || 'HCS System';
  message = message || 'HCS Dialog Box';
  size = size || 'lg';

  var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: true,
    size: size,
    title: '<strong>' + title + '</strong>',
    message: message
  });
  dialog.prop("id", "dialog-box");
};

$("#show-data").on("click", function() {
  var dialogTitle = "Data History",
    table = $('<table>').addClass('table'),
    thead = $('<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Title</th></tr></thead>'),
    tbody = $('<tbody>');

  if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    var tr = $('<tr><td colspan="3">No records were found.</td></tr>');
    tbody.append(tr);
  } else {
    for (key in data) {
      var tr = $('<tr>').prop('id', 'row_' + key);
      tbody.append(tr);
      tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].name ? data[key].name : "N/A"));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].age ? data[key].age : "N/A"));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].title ? data[key].title : "N/A"));
      tr.append($('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary edit-data" data-recid="' + key + '">Edit</button></td>'));
    }
  }

  table.append(thead);
  table.append(tbody);
  dialogBox(dialogTitle, table, "xl");
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit-data", function() {
  $("#dialog-box").modal("hide");

  var recID = $(this).data("recid");

  if (!$.isEmptyObject(data[recID])) {
    $("#dialog-box").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    });

    $("#frm_name").val(data[recID].name);
    $("#frm_age").val(data[recID].age);
    $("#frm_title").val(data[recID].title);
    $("#frm_modal").modal("show");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.3.2/bootbox.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" type="button" id="show-data">Show Data</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="frm_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="frm-data" name="data_frm" id="data_frm" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="frm_name">Name:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_name" id="frm_name" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="50" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="frm_age">Age:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_age" id="frm_age" placeholder="Enter Age" maxlength="2" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="frm_title">Title:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_title" id="frm_title" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="100" required>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary review-apply" data-modal="er_modal" data-update-option="">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```